# Get result of command line request and open file

Tags: c++, string, file, command-line, char

I use following function :

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

std::string filepath = exec("locate filename.txt");
```

It returns a `std::string` and I convert it using `.c_str()` in :

`std::ifstream file(filepath.c_str(), ios::in);`

But after I try :

```
if(file)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "File missing : " + filepath << std::endl;
}
```

And I get :

`File missing : /path/to/file`

Comment: What is your question? I'm guessing, the file doesn't exist!

Comment: Try writing the error message like `std::cerr << "File missing : -" + filepath << "-" << std::endl;` Then could quite easily see if there's any leading or trailing space in the string that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

Unix command `locate` outputs newline (`'\n'`) character after each file name, so you need to strip this character from the output of `locate` command before using it as file name.  You could probably use method `pop_back` of class `string` for this.

Also note, that `locate` may output several file names and file names may contain newline characters inside.

Comment: The solution to file names containing newline characters is `locate -0 filename.txt` and split on terminating `\0` characters rather than newline.